# Python script to delete Variables that have no data - not enough memory?

Tags: python, spss

I'm working with a SPSS (v. 24) data file that has 47,000 variables, and most of them are empty (all values are missing). I'd like to drop the variables that contain only missing data.

I've tried the following spssaux2 python script:

```
begin program.
import spssaux2

spssaux2.FindEmptyVars(delete=True)
end program.
```

Which seemed at first to work correctly but then I got the following error:

> The AGGREGATE command specifies too many break variables plus new
>   variables. Run with more memory

If you can provide assistance, I'd be most grateful.